# coin change function using unbounded knapsack python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, coin-change

I'm trying to write a coin change function. The idea is that I have unlimited denominations and whatever value and trying to see what kind of change I can get. I thought this could be done like an unbounded knapsack program but I'm getting a weird output and I don't understand what it means. I thought maybe it was because I was entering the values and decimals and thought to change the value in the function to float but that gave me an error and wouldn't run the program. Can someone explain what my current output is saying? Is it possible to do this kind of thing with decimals? How can I improve this?

```
#change_tuple is the type of coin and the value of the coin
#change_amount is how much change to get
def make_change(coin_tuples, change_amount):

    #max_change = change_amount
    #max_change = [0]*(change_amount)
    max_change = [0]*(change_amount + 1)

    for current_total in range(change_amount + 1):
        total_change = 0

        for coin_type, coin_value in coin_tuples:
            if (coin_type <= current_total):
                max_change_using_coin = coin_value + max_change[current_total - coin_type]
                total_change = max(max_change_using_coin, total_change)

        max_change[current_total] = total_change

    return max_change

coin_tuples = ([1, .01], [5, .05], [10, .1], [25, .25], [50, .5], [100, 1])
change_amount = 20
make_change(coin_tuples, change_amount)
```

OUTPUT: [0,
 0.01,
 0.02,
 0.03,
 0.04,
 0.05,
 0.060000000000000005,
 0.07,
 0.08,
 0.09,
 0.1,
 0.11000000000000001,
 0.12000000000000001,
 0.13,
 0.14,
 0.15000000000000002,
 0.16000000000000003,
 0.17000000000000004,
 0.18000000000000005,
 0.19000000000000006,
 0.20000000000000007]

Comment: Your output is incorrect, you also are experiencing floating point issues and limitations https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Thank you. I know it's incorrect but I'm trying to understand why it's giving me that output.

Comment: @user1248923 numbers in decimal cannot be represent in binary exactly so, we have to use approximations; and if you take a lot of precision into account you are bound to find the difference from what you expect. Read the python or IEEE(http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/) docs on this subject.